# get the expression out of solve results

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

Cosider the simple solution:

```
 sol: solve(b * x - a, x);
```

```
     a
[x = -]
     b
```

how can I get the expression part `sol: a / b` out of the above result?

**solution** was offered to me [here](https://twitter.com/jweilharter/status/1367847083311570950?s=20).

Comment: In what way is the offered solution not working for you? What is it that you want to do that the offered solution does not cover? A different way to solve it is to say: `sol: rhs (first (sol))`. By the way, about the other problem in the tweets, note the name of the plotting function is `wxplot2d`, not `wxplot2D`.

Comment: hey, @RobertDodier thanks for the comment. If by the offered solution you mean the one below, it is not a WxMaxima/Maxima solution. If you mean the one I have linked in the Tweet, then it is a perfectly fine solution. I'm just gonna add it as an answer below. Also, feel free to offer your alternative solution as an answer if you will. 

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Johann Weilharter](https://twitter.com/jweilharter/status/1367847083311570950?s=20) I found one way to extract the expression:

```
 sol: ev(x, solve(b * x - a, x)[1]);
```

Of course, if there is more than one solution, you need to change `1` to the specific instance.

Alternatively, as pointed out in the comments of the question, one can also use

```
sol: rhs(first(solve(b * x - a, x)));
```

oneliner to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a symbolic evaluation library. If you are considering a python implementation, you can use [SymPy](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/sympy.html).

```py
import sympy as sym

x = sym.Symbol('x')
b = sym.Symbol('b')
a = sym.Symbol('a')
sol = sym.solve((b * x - a), x)
print(sol)

------
[a/b]
```

Comment: I didn't care for a Python/SymPy answer. But anyway thank you. 

Comment: The tags at the bottom of the question indicate that it is a Maxima/WxMaxima question.  but no worries. You did a great job helping a fella here anyway.